# Consequences of using URL Rewrite module for 404 errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config, custom-error-pages

I have several rewrite rules which vary from setting a default language in the URL (en/fr) to rewriting my actual pages.

Due to these Rewrite rules it does not appear that my `<httpErrors>` or `<customErrors>` are working. Therefore, I've opted to add the following rewrite rule:

```
<rule name="Redirect404" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="/enrolment(/fr|/en)(/)?" />
        </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="/enrolment{C:1}/404-not-found" />
</rule>
```

My `404.aspx` page contains the following code to signify that it's response type should be 404:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
    Response.Status = "404 Not Found";
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
}
```

Is there a downside to using this method as opposed to using `<httpErrors>` or `<customErrors>`? If so, what?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Why would you manually rewrite an invalid URL to a 404 page when the default behavior will do that for you? What do you gain from it?

Comment: The default behavior isn't working. Rather than redirecting to my custom 404 page (when using `<httpErrors>` or `<customErrors>`), it continues to redirect to the IIS 404 page. When commenting out all of my rewrite rules, then it works! Therefore I confirm that my rewrite rules hinder the default behavior.

Comment: I think you should try to fix the problem with your redirections as opposed to going around the default behavior. The issue is clearly related to your rewrites so I would suggest eliminating rules until you figure out which one is causing the odd behavior.

Comment: But it there an actual issue with deviating from the default behavior? The URL Rewrite module was introduced after the capability to add custom error pages. As it stands right now, the URL rewrite method is working flawlessly from what I can observe. I suppose I should alter my question to: From a semantic perspective, will this cause any foreseeable issues?

Comment: You are taking a natural behavior (I look for something, it's not there) and replacing it by what you **think** it means for something not to be there. If you follow down this path, it will lead to errors down the road. You have been warned. :-)